# JavaScript Currency (USD) Function Browser Compatibility

Tags: javascript, tostring, currency

I am currently working on a *"Return on Investment Calculator"* in JavaScript.
Whenever a user enters a few values into the calculator, JavaScript calculates their *"Return on Investment".*

I've written a var that contains a USD($) function to convert the outcome of the calculation into a **USD** value.
So when the outcome of the calculation is `10000`, the outcome will be `$10,000`.

Now the strange thing is, the function works in **Google Chrome** & **Opera**.
But it completely ignores the function in **Safari** & **Firefox**.

This is what the function looks like:

```
 var lib = {
      usd: function (amount) {
          return (amount)
              .toLocaleString("en-US", {
                  style: "currency"
                  , currency: "USD"
                  , maximumFractionDigits: 0
              });
      },
```

And this is how I render the values + USD into my HTML/Bootstrap.

```
    $('span#roi').text(lib.usd(roi));
```

I am fairly new to JavaScript, so I'm not sure what to do at this point.

Comment: Firefox doesn't like `maximumFractionDigits` to be less than 2 for USD. I don't know about Safari.

Comment: @Pointy That worked for Firefox, won't do anything for Safari. And is there any way to parse out the .00 at the end besides the .replace method?

Comment: Probably not; I'm not sure what the rationale is behind disallowing the cents value in the first place, but since it gives you back a string then manipulating it as a string is pretty much all you can do.

Comment: Interestingly, it looks like Firefox, at least, does the right thing, according to [the spec](https://tc39.github.io/ecma402/#sec-initializenumberformat). See lines 19 through 27, especially 27, where it says maximumFractionDigits for currency should be the number of digits listed for the specified `currency` name in ISO 4217. For USD, that's 2.